# I can not execute pptk.viewer() on google colab

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds, viewer, pptk

I can not visualize point clouds with pptk on google colab. It stays running permanently and I have to stop it manually.
It does work with Jupyter, but I wanted to use it on colab.
What I'm doing is just this:

```
import numpy as np
import pptk

x = np.random.rand(100, 3)
v = pptk.viewer(x)
v.set(point_size=0.0001)
```

I am also installing pptk with:

```
!pip install pptk
```

Does anybody knows why isn't it working?
Thank you!